# How can I build this type of graph in android?

Tags: android, graph, charts

Any library you guys can recommend, or better if you know how to do it without third-parties implementations.

I want to get something like this;

[image]

Comment: you have to use third party there are many(https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=graph)  or you have to create your own which requires good knowledge of customviews/canvas apis and mathematics also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MPChart Library for line Graph

```
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart
```

For example :

https://medium.com/@makkenasrinivasarao1/line-chart-implementation-with-mpandroidchart-af3dd11804a7